# Bluetooth scan Background iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I'm starting the central manager like this:

```
[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
```

The offical Apple documentation states the following:

> Apps that have specified the bluetooth-central background mode are
>   allowed to scan while in the background. That said, they must
>   explicitly scan for one or more services by specifying them in the
>   serviceUUIDs parameter. The CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey
>   scan option is ignored while scanning in the background.

Source: [Apple offical documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBCentralManager/scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:)

If i understand it correctly i have to provide a CBUUID for a service so the scanning will continue when the App goes to the background. The device i am interested in seems to be not connectable (kCBAdvDataIsConnectable is 0). Therefore i guess no services are offered. Is there any way to get the advertisment data anyway in the background in this scenario?

Comment: If the device is advertising a service then you can scan for that services's UUID. If the device isn't advertising a service then you cannot scan for it. To reduce power in the background, iOS does not allow scanning without a specific service nominated

Comment: Unfortunately the device if only advertising it's name and that it is not connectable. Do i understand it correctly that my use case is not possible with that kind of set up?